# $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_p[x])$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to solve $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/x^{2015})$, so I need to find the prime ideals of $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_p[x])$ that contains $x^{2015}$, can anybody help me with that spectrum?

Comment: Is $\mathbb Z_p$ the $p$-adics?

Comment: In any case, suppose you have a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in some ring and that ideal contains $a^N$ for some positive $N$. Then what can you say?

Comment: It would be $p=<a>$? but in this case with $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ the ideal $p=<a^p>$ for $p$ prime with $p<N$?
I wonder also if $x^{2015}$ is irreductible on $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$, because if it is irreductible, then the quotient will be a field.

Comment: What I wanted you to conclude was that $a \in \mathfrak{p}$. This follows from the defining property of a prime ideal and induction. This should make the problem a lot easier.